# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

As I looked for answers from google and here most of the answer says that you are trying to use length on an NSArray which is not supported.

The problem here is I don't even use any NSArray or length in my code.

I got a

```
NSMutableArray *filteredContent;
```

where `filteredContent` will contain dictionaries from a plist.

Everything runs great until writing `cell.textLabel.text` on the cell for `tableView`.
Checked with `NSLog` and the content is indeed an array.

This is how I try to write the cell text:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[[self.filteredContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
```

But it gives me error so i changed it to:

```
NSString *myValue = [self.filteredContent valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
cell.textLabel.text=myValue;
```

Yet the result is the same. I have no idea what I am getting this error.

Further details:

```
[results addObject:@[recipe]];
```

This is where i create my main array and than pass it to the `PageView` with segue `filteredContent = results`

---

EDIT:

`recipe = arrayOfPlist[i];` where arrayOfPlist

```
NSArray *arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
//Output to NSLog(@"FIltered Content :  %@", self.filteredContent);
FIltered Content :  (
        (
            {
                category = main;
                difficultyLevel = "3/5";
                numberOfPerson = 5;
                recipeDetail = "Bulguru koy su koy beklet pisir ye ";
                recipeImage = "nohutlu-pilav.jpg";
                recipeIngredients = "pirinc,tereyag tuz,bulgur";
                recipeName = "Bulgurlu Pilav";
                time = "25 dk";
            }
        ),
        (
            {
                category = main;
                difficultyLevel = "3/5";
                numberOfPerson = 5;
                recipeDetail = "Bulguru koy su koy beklet pisir ye ";
                recipeImage = "nohutlu-pilav.jpg";
                recipeIngredients = "pirinc,tereyag tuz,bulgur";
                recipeName = "Bulgurlu Pilav";
                time = "25 dk";
            }
        )
    )

    2014-04-27 02:47:41.704 deneme2[19820:60b] VALUE IN FILTERED TABLE  is (
        "Bulgurlu Pilav" // this is what i want to write to the cell label and i get it with myValue-look a bit above
    )
```

Comment: Are you parsing JSON? Where you think you have a string you actually have an array.

Comment: @rmaddy no i m not parsing JSON. I m using same TableViewController changed with few filters and all worked fine until now.So i don't think that's the problem beside. are you telling me that i m trying to set my cellLabel.text to a Array?

Comment: Yes, `myValue` is actually left pointing to an `NSArray`, not an `NSString`. It's probably due to misusing `valueForKey:`. If you can't figure out how to get the desired string within the array, add details about your data structure.

Comment: So you think thats the problem that cause this exception?

Comment: @rmaddy added all details .

Comment: As I said, update your question with details about your actual data structure (such as the log output of `NSLog(@"%@", self.filteredContent);`) and point out the value you are trying to access.

Comment: @rmaddy i think i added everything you need.Waitin for a feedback now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the output of your data, you have an extra array in there. So you want this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.filteredContent[indexPath.row][0][@"recipeName"];
```

Each element of your filteredContentArray is another array. Each of those inner arrays has the dictionary with the data you want.

Comment: Where you do this - `[results addObject:@[recipe]];` you are adding an element with a single element, which is your recipe arrayOfPlist.  You probably just wanted `[results addObject:recipe]` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 oh how did i miss that.Yea that was the trick.Thank you kind stranger

Answer (score 1):

Do what @rmaddy suggested or:

Change:

```
[results addObject:@[recipe]];
```

to:

```
[results addObject:recipe]
```

---

### Explanation:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length : unrecognized selector sent to instance

This error tells us:

1. Object is an `NSArray` (*somewhere, somehow*)
2. Method called on this `NSArray` object was `length`

   - But `NSArray` **does not** have a `length` method
   - It seems somewhere a call to `length` method was sent, most probably on an `NSString` object that is actually holding an `NSArray` object rather than an `NSString` object.

Firstly note that when you specify:

1. `@[]`

   - you are implying that the object to be created is an `NSArray` object.
   - ref: [Objective-C literals for NSDictionary, NSArray, and NSNumber](http://cocoaheads.tumblr.com/post/17757846453/objective-c-literals-for-nsdictionary-nsarray-and)

So when you do: `[results addObject:@[recipe]];`:

- `@[recipe]`
  **is equivalent to**
- `[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:recipe, nil]`

So... you're basically taking `recipe`, putting it in an array, then adding this array object within `results` (*which is another array*).

Later when you come to `PageView`

```
[[self.filteredContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
```

will return you an array of values for the key `recipeName`.

So basically, your string is holding an array and not the string object.
Now... whether you called `length` on it or not, somewhere in the lifecycle, `length` is being called on `cell.textLabel.text` and raising this error.